# What does cause such high CPU fan speeds?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cpu

So, everything worked fine yesterday. Today, my CPU fan seems upset.

[image]

It alternatively goes up to a high speed of around 5000 rpm, then back down to a low speed of around 2300 rpm, and up again, in cycles.
The screenshot below is a graph of CPU fan speed over time. See, it follows a pattern.

[image]

Temperature of cores does not vary as CPU fan speed goes up or down. Usually they are correlated.
I have to add, I am not running any application. I only have firefox open with 2 or 3 tabs. I am basically sitting here arms crossed.

I also need to point that the CPU history graph shows bursts of usage that can go as high as 80%. They seem to last a fraction of a second, but they appear every few seconds. IDK if that's something normal or not.

Can you point me to some process to help to identify what causes this issue ? Or even better, do you know what could cause this ? (linux mint 17)

Comment: eliminate mechanical causes first ... blockages, fan interference, etc.

Comment: The max temperature looks pretty hot.  Something, maybe Firefox, is causing the CPU to heat up very quickly?

Comment: Your chart does not give us much information, since both the top and the bottom are labeled 0 degrees Celcius... also, there are no units on the x-axis: these would also help in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Use `htop` and sort by `PERCENT_CPU` to see the process(es) with high CPU usage. if you prefer a GUI, use system monitor.

Comment: Check thermal paste state (between CPU and radiator/fan), check solid mechanics fixation between CPU and radiator/fan.